# Can Axis2 1.4.1 call an endpoint with net.pipe//host...?

Tags: java, web-services, url, pipe, axis

We have a web service client which uses the Axis2 1.4.1 framework and currently we just call the web service with an URL like `http://...`. But now we have to change this to a so called `net.pipe` URL.

Is this possible just to configure this new `net.pipe` URL or is this not possible with this Axis2 framework version?

Comment: As I have seen this net.pipe is only for .Net platform available, is this true?